# Питон , из кортежа в строку

Tags: python, числа

Дан кортеж `{"34", "76", "0", "532"}`
Как вытащить числа из этого кортежа чтобы при выводе имело такой вид?

```
34, 76, 0, 532
```

У меня только мысли засунуть в список, потом вытащить, но всё равно есть кавычки, как от них избавиться?

```
a = {"34", "76", "0", "532"}
lst=[]
for i in a:
    lst.append(i)
print(lst)
['532', '34', '0', '76']
```

Comment: `', '.join([i for i in {"34", "76", "0", "532"}])`

Comment: `{"34", "76", "0", "532"}` не кортеж, а *множество*, без дубликатов и без сохранения порядка. Кортежи в *круглых* скобках: ("34", "76", "0", "532"). Они упорядоченные и позволяют дубликаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как минимум, (если есть уверенность, что в кортеже только числа) можно в список добавлять числа, а не строки, т. е. вместо `lst.append(i)`, добавлять `lst.append(int(i))`, но есть способ короче:

```
", ".join(a)
```

Вывод будет

```
'0, 34, 532, 76'
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас множество, не кортеж. Поэтому порядок элементов не будет сохранен.
Вывести можно так

`print(', '.join(a))`

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться распаковкой аргумента.

`print(*{"34", "76", "0", "532"}, sep=', ')`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать числа из строк, примените функцию `int()`.

Чтобы применить функцию к *всякому элементу* кортежи / списка / множества, используйте функцию `map()`, в которой *в качестве первого параметра будет эта функция (без скобок)*:

```
map(int, а)        # a = {"34", "76", "0", "532"}
```

Результатом будет *генератор*, из которого можете сделать *кортеж*, *список* или *множество* функциями `tuple()`, `list()` или  `set()`. Например для

```
print(list(map(int, a)))
```

будет вывод

> ```
> [532, 34, 0, 76]
> ```

и для

```
for i in map(int, a):       # в цикле for list() не нужен
    print(i)
```

будет вывод

> ```
> 76
> 0
> 532
> 34
> ```

или же для

```
for i in map(int, a):
    print("{:5}".format(i))    # 5 значит число позиций для цифр (может выть другое)
```

будет вывод

> ```
>    76
>    34
>   532
>     0
> ```